# Is this usage correct for using isometric log ratio [ILR] transform with counts data (compositional)?

Tags: correlation, count-data, compositional-data, logarithm, aitchison-geometry

If one wanted to construct a simple pairwise correlation matrix from an compositional data table using an ILR transform preprocessing step, would this usage violate any assumptions with the transform?

**Is it valid to use the ILR transform with respect to the attributes instead of the samples if they are scaled?**

The ILR transform is for compositional data which is essentially a sample of a population in the form of integer counts. This data has the problem of some samples containing more total counts than others so many methods like correlation can be skewed.  The following figure illustrates the situation of 2 populations having the same counts for all attributes except one.  When the populations are compared, most attributes appear to be down-regulated when in reality there is only one that is upregulated in one of the populations.

[image: image2]
https://docs.qiime2.org/2018.6/tutorials/gneiss/

Essentially, the below code does the following:

(1) Generate random compositional data table

(2) Transform to relative abundance so each sample/row sums to 1

(3) ILR transform along axis 0 to end up (n-1 samples, m=attributes)

(4) Pairwise correlation

```
from skbio.stats.composition import ilr
# Utility functions
def generate_compositional_data(shape=(8,13), random_state=0):
    def get_labels(prefix, size):
        return list(map(lambda x:"_".join([prefix, str(x)]), range(size)))
    data = np.random.RandomState(random_state).randint(low=0, high=1000, size=shape)

    return pd.DataFrame(data, 
                        index=get_labels("patient",shape[0]),
                        columns=get_labels("Otu",shape[1]),
)
def relative_abundance(X):
    scaling_factor = X.sum(axis=1).values.reshape((-1,1))
    return pd.DataFrame(X.values/scaling_factor, index=X.index, columns=X.columns)

# Generate data
df_otus = generate_compositional_data() 
df_otus.sum(axis=1)
# patient_0    7295
# patient_1    5903
# patient_2    8105
# patient_3    7315
# patient_4    6269
# patient_5    6351
# patient_6    6545
# patient_7    6163
# dtype: int64

# Relative abundance
df_scaled = relative_abundance(df_otus)

df_scaled.sum(axis=1)
# patient_0    1.0
# patient_1    1.0
# patient_2    1.0
# patient_3    1.0
# patient_4    1.0
# patient_5    1.0
# patient_6    1.0
# patient_7    1.0
# dtype: float64
df_ilr = pd.DataFrame(ilr(df_scaled.T).T, columns=df_scaled.columns)
# print(df_ilr.head())
#       Otu_0     Otu_1     Otu_2     Otu_3     Otu_4     Otu_5     Otu_6  \
# 0 -0.055884  1.319409  0.053333 -0.955416  0.377799  0.478101 -0.147712   
# 1  0.126634 -0.643007 -0.185855  1.438424 -0.073371 -0.339283  1.654090   
# 2 -0.196348  0.920854 -0.352120  0.149329 -0.115821 -0.208206 -0.431096   
# 3 -0.112610 -1.092643  0.119336 -1.024966 -0.177794  0.759426  0.845943   
# 4 -0.208179  0.587506  1.430151 -1.318172  2.240699 -0.560585 -0.477439   
df_sim = df_ilr.corr()
df_sim
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking us to check your R code? I can't see a question here otherwise.

Comment: No, ILR transform is for compositional data which is essentially a sample of a population in the form of integer counts.  This data has the problem of some samples containing more total counts than others so many methods like correlation can be skewed.  I am asking if this same method can be applied with respect to scaled attributes instead of with respect to samples.  I will add this to the question. Also, this is Python.

Comment: You're right; it's Python and I should have spotted that. But my query is what is your question that is on-topic here? I know what ILR is (and I don't think it's confined to integer input at all, as we _measure_ amounts for many compositions; % sand, silt, clay in soils; % fat, carbohydrates, protein in food). I am still struggling with your question: it is not surprising that e.g. you get different results for number of unemployed people in different countries as compared with % of unemployed.

Comment: Oh interesting use case of ILR.  I've recently just read about it so I'm trying to make sure the use case is valid.  My understanding of ILR was that it assumes each attribute is a component of a particular composition so when the ratios are calculated it makes sense to apply the ILR transform.  It seemed weird for me to imagine the reverse case in which the ratios are compared with respect to a particular attribute.  Maybe my understanding is incorrect but I didn't want to find out down the line that the analysis was invalid using ILR in this way.  Thanks for your response :)